# Jest test case error in react-native using external plugin

Tags: javascript, android, sqlite, react-native, jestjs

I am using react-native init to create a react-native project. I am using https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage library for SQLite bindings.

I have a DbConnector.jest-test.js unit tests file. Contents are

```
import DbConnector from '../app/components/DbConnector.js';
// Note: test renderer must be required after react-native.
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

it('renders correctly', () => {
const tree = renderer.create(
<DbConnector />
);
});
```

When I am running jest, I am getting following error even if by default node_modules are ignored. I am using react-native preset in package.json

```
Test suite failed to run

ReferenceError: window is not defined

  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native-sqlite-storage/lib/sqlite.core.js:53:10)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native-sqlite-storage/sqlite.js:10:12)
  at Object.<anonymous> (app/components/DbConnector.js:3:31)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
```

Imports in DbConnector.js are as:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Button, Alert, 
AsyncStorage } from 'react-native'
import SQLite from 'react-native-sqlite-storage'
```

Answer (score 3):

You should try to mock react-native-sqlite-storage before your test.

```
jest.mock('react-native-sqlite-storage');
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your issue `window is not defined` is coming from this line: https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage/blob/master/lib/sqlite.core.js#L53

It looks like your test is missing an import of `react-native` and should look like this:

```
import 'react-native';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
```

If that doesn't work, you might be able to follow these steps for using `JSDOM` [from this guide](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/guides/jsdom.html) (which is from Enzyme, but might still help!)